# For loop issue in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on asp.net mvc4 and i am using razor for displaying data in my view.I am using one for loop in my view.my loop code is like below.

```
 **@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    if (i<(@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductInfo[5].Value)))
   {
     <img src="../../Images/star-on.png" />
   }
    else
    {
      <img src="../../Images/star-off.png" />
    }
  }**
```

In my above for loop in if condition i am trying to bind the number like 4.But it gives error like below

***operator ' ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int'  and 'system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring'***

But when i display this razor code in my view like its showing the number "4".The code is like below.

**@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductInfo[5].Value)**

Comment: `i<(@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductInfo[5].Value))` Why are you comparing a number to HTML? Why do you expect it to work? Is `<span>` greater than or equal to 6?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check against the value not the display for the value

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    if (i < Model.ProductInfo[5].Value)  @* <-- This line changed *@
   {
     <img src="../../Images/star-on.png" />
   }
    else
    {
      <img src="../../Images/star-off.png" />
    }
  }
```

**Update**

If your `Model.ProductInfo[5].Value` is of type `string` you need to do the following (providing you are not willing to change `Value`'s type)

```
 @{
     int productFiveValue;
     bool canConvert = Int32.TryParse(Model.ProductInfo[5].Value, out productFiveValue);
 }
 @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
     if (canConvert && i < productFiveValue)
     {
         <img src="../../Images/star-on.png" />
     }
     else
     {
          <img src="../../Images/star-off.png" />
     }
 }
```

Comment: mr NinjaNye Its now giving me the error like operator ' ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int'  and 'string'

Comment: Below your answer? I can't see it?

Comment: Is ProductInfo[5].Value of type string

Comment: i tried (i < Model.ProductInfo[5].Value).Count() it's giving me different value.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote or accept the answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an HTML helper here, they usually return MvcHtmlString instances and you can't compare them to numbers. This should work:

```
if (i < Model.ProductInfo[5].Value)
```

Comment: mr NinjaNye Its now giving me the error like operator ' ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int'  and 'string'

Comment: @user2534261 What returns from Model.ProductInfo[5].Value?

Comment: it returns "4" number

Comment: @user2534261 as an int?